# Where to contact eBay support on-line?

Tags: ebay

I'd like to contact eBay regarding their site or general problems which I'm having. I've tried [Customer Service](http://ocsnext.ebay.com/ocs/home) page, but I couldn't find any contact form apart of *FAQ*, *Community* or 'Call me' (where I don't want to waste my time calling them only because of their problems). Every time when I'm clicking *Contact us*, I'm redirected to useless *Popular solutions* page.

Is there any standard, simpler way of contacting eBay support on-line via webform, e-mail or chat to talk with human?

Comment: Not in the US anyway. But I have had decent luck with the "call me" feature, being careful to do this during off-peak hours. You might add what you expect would be better online vs. on the phone. If you just want to give them suggestions or advice, there is a "Tell us what you think" link at the top of your My eBay page.

Comment: I am able to see the _Contact us_ page, but it seems to require a valid session. Could you try to log out of eBay, log in again, and then click the _Contact us_ button?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit maze, but here are the simple steps:

1. Go to *[Help & Contact](http://ocsnext.ebay.co.uk/ocs/home)* page (at the top or the bottom of the page).
2. Follow *[Need our help? Contact us](http://ocsnext.ebay.co.uk/ocs/cuhome)* link.
3. Select the following topics: *Buying*, *Paying for items*, *Trouble paying for an item*.
4. *Chat with us* option should appear.

[image: eBay support - Contact us - Chat]

In addition if you follow *Hard of hearing or visually impaired?* link, you will be redirected to *Contact us* form.

[image: eBay support - eBay Customer Service - Contact us - web form]